# find number of rows in returned mysql result (nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js

When using felixge's mysql for node.js, how can I ask the result object for the number of returned rows? I have a rather expensive query so I don't want to run a `COUNT(*)` first, just to then run a query a second time.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If it's a select query, just take the length of the returned array.

```
connection.query(sql, [var1,var2], function(err, results) {
    numRows = results.length;
});
```

If it's an update/delete query, the returned dictionary will have an affectedRows variable.

```
connection.query(sql, [var1,var2], function(err, result) {
    numRows = result.affectedRows;
});
```

Comment: I really wish there was better documentation for that library than just the readme.md on github. I figured this out not long after I posted (but obviously long enough that I forgot to come back and answer it :P).

Comment: Note that `affectedRows` by default will be the found (matched) rows, not rows with actual changed data unless you set a connection flag to turn off `FOUND_ROWS`.  This matters if you are trying to figure out how many rows were actually modified.  Or you can use the newer `changedRows` value. See https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-flags

Comment: @Huckle same after 8 years

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the examples in the readme just look at the length property of the rows object (i.e. rows.length).

Answer (score -2):

With the version of mssql 2.1.2 as of 2015-04-13:

delete from DeviceAccountLinks
where DeviceAccountId = @deviceAccountId
and DeviceType = @deviceType

statement will produce no results as 'undefined'

I have changed the statement to:

delete from DeviceAccountLinks
where DeviceAccountId = @deviceAccountId
and DeviceType = @deviceType;
select @@rowcount "rowCount"

to get the output of: [{rowCount:1}]