# MySql Unique Index how to generate appropriate Response?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple Database that contains a table with all the users of my game. I want the user names and email addresses to be unique, so  have set them to have a unique index.

Whenever a new user register for the game, this statement is executed:

```
tmpQUERY = "INSERT INTO vertix_users (user_name, user_email, user_pass) " +
    "VALUES (" + mysql.escape(userName) +
    ", " + mysql.escape(userEmail) + 
    ", " + mysql.escape(userPass) + ") " +
    "ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
    "RETURN 'This username already exists'";
```

I can just do a simple INSERT IGNORE to avoid duplicate user names or email addresses. But what I would like to do, is generate some useful feedback for the user; "This name has been taken." or "Email already in use". The code above is an arbitrary example of what I thought could work. How can I achieve something along those lines?

Comment: You would generally do this in your application, not the database.

Comment: This query is executed from a Node.js server. What do you mean? Should the app make several requests to see if the name/email already exists?

Comment: Use te affecetd rows in node with INSERT IGNORE,if > 0 echo out a message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199842/find-number-of-rows-in-returned-mysql-result-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to run a previous query to check whether the name already exists. Registering process is not a very demanding process, since every user registers only once. So I don't think it is worth it to try to do this in only one query. Besides, with a separate "checkUserName" process, you can check it, if you want, before all the registration form is sent to the server. For example, as soon as the user finishes to write his desired username.