# SQL SELECT & UPDATE Syntax

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to do a SELECT and a UPDATE in SQL, using a single Statement. After some Google FU i can't seem to find any documentation on it. Or maybe i'm looking for the wrong thing.

```
inquirer
        .prompt([{
            name: "updateID",
            type: "input",
            message: "What's the ID of the product you'd like to update?"
        },
        {
            name: "updateQuantity",
            type: "input",
            message: "How many units would you like to add to inventory?"
        }]).then(function(answer) {
            connection.query("SELECT id, stock_quantity FROM products WHERE ?", 
            {
                id: parseInt(answer.updateID)
            }, function(err, res) {

            })

        })
```

I'd hope there's a way to do a SELECT and UPDATE in a single statement.

Comment: Do you want to select something and then update based on the result of the select or do you want to update something and then select the updated value?

Comment: 'add to inventory' do you mean insert or update, like [IODKU](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)? Please explain your requirements more clearly.

Comment: I want to SELECT a row in the table by the ID, then UPDATE one the values in a column of that row...

Comment: sorry. I'm a new developer and this is my first question on Stack Overflow. So i'm learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically want to read the data for that product, you don't *need* to do a `SELECT` before you `UPDATE` the value. Based on your code, this query should do what you want:

```
UPDATE products
SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + ?
WHERE id = ?
```

If you do want to read the data as well, you have to perform separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: Additionally to this you can use the `res.affectedRows` to determine if the row actually existed like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199842/find-number-of-rows-in-returned-mysql-result-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to SELECT a row in the table by the ID, then UPDATE one the values in a column of that row...

In order to update only certain rows, you can use a single [`UPDATE` query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) with a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column>=<value>
WHERE <id_column>=<id>;
```