# Check Result of Query in NodeJS?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I have the following MySQL query in NodeJS which checks for the existence of "tag1";

```
sql.query("SELECT tagname, tagid FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?", [tag1], (err, res, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }
    console.log("found tag1: ", { tag1 });
    result(null, { tag1 });
  })
```

If the tag does not exist I'd like to fire off another query. If I were using PHP I'd do this;

```
if ($myTagQuery->num_rows >= 0){}
```

What should I do in NodeJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find number of rows in returned mysql result (nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199842/find-number-of-rows-in-returned-mysql-result-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with

```
if (result < 1) {
console.log("tag1 doesn't exist");
// do your query
}
```